# Which miles rules apply in code share

Tags: loyalty-programs, star-alliance, singapore-airlines, code-share, air-new-zealand

I am a Lufthansa Star Alliance Gold status member. I plan to fly to New Zealand next year, buyng a ticket from Air New Zealand. Part of the journey is operated by Singapore Airlines. Who determines the miles earned as per ticket class:

- Lufthansa, the programme I belong to, ( unlikely..), using their rules for miles earned with partners
- Air New Zealand, the ticket issuer ( got the money)
- Singapore Air ( the airline flying part of the journey)

I want to be sure I will earn status miles for the journey. All three are Star Alliance members.

Comment: Note that the fact the NZ is issuing the ticket while SQ is operating the flight does not necessarily mean it's a code-share. What counts is the flight number as shown on your ticket. This may (or may not, depending on LH rules) have an influence on the actual miles you will get.

Answer (score 11):

When it comes to putting miles into your account with Frequent Flyer Program X, it is always Frequent Flyer X's rules that count. The fact that ANZ would give your their miles for the flight if you were an ANZ member is irrelevant. Generally, it doesn't matter which *A program you join, but there are oddities when a particular fare class earns miles in one program but not in another. There is generally nothing you can do about that.

When you fly on a partner you have the added complication of mapping the fare classes used by the ticket-seller, which is what you saw when you made your purchase decision, to the equivalent fare classes used by your FF program, which is what will determine the miles you get.

Miles and More has a page about [flights on Singapore Airlines](http://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/de/earn/flight/offer?nodeid=2510507&l=en&cid=18002). You will need to work out what LH fare class you're in and then you can see if you will earn 0.5x, 1x, or (unlikely) more than the distance you flew.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way of finding out your mileage earning on a partner airline or codeshare operating each segment of your trip is to plug the fare class into the [wheretocredit](http://www.wheretocredit.com/) web site.

You can see the Miles & More earning on Singapore airlines [here](http://www.wheretocredit.com/singapore-airlines). You'll need to know the fare class for each segment which is not always readily apparent.

Answer (score 7):

One of the complexities of codeshare flights in the *alliance network is that the mileage earnings are based on the rates of the operating carrier, not the marketing carrier.  (in your case the rate of Singapore airlines).  This means you would need to check the fare class of the singapore airlines flight against the earnings table of lufthansa's M&M earnings table (see the link in Kate Gregory's post).

To find out the fare class for this Singapore Airline's segment best is to contact the Marketing carrier (Air New Zealand) and ask how your Air New Zealand fare class maps to that of Singapore airlines.

(I tried to do a search online hoping I would find a fare class mapping table between these two airlines but unfortunately found nothing...)